# Animate UIButton with Autolayout with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, autolayout

Hello Community I just want to animate an UIView exactly an UIButton. But it really don't work for me.

```
 self.introConstraints.constant = self.view.frame.width
    self.view.needsUpdateConstraints()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6){
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

This is how my code looks like.

Comment: Leave out `self.view.needsUpdateConstraints()` and it should work. You mustn't ever call that method, if you replace it with `self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` it should be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

=> try this one :-

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6 ,
    animations:
 {
        self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6)

},

```
completion: { 

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6){

        self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }
})
```

=> If you want to more  bouncing effect  with spring animation.:-

=>try folowing code:

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func animateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6)

   UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0,

   delay: 0,
   usingSpringWithDamping: CGFloat(0.20),

   initialSpringVelocity: CGFloat(6.0),

   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,

   animations: {

        self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
   },
      completion: { Void in()  }
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really crazy but guys make sure you set the correct constraints that will help you.

it should work with something like this

```
 self.startConstraints.constant = self.view.frame.width - self.startButton.frame.width
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6){
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove self.view.needsUpdateConstraints()